# recently harvested an old hard drive from ASUS laptop

Tags: hard-disk, windows, macos

I recently harvested an old hard drive from an old ASUS laptop running with windows XP (see photo). Two questions now:

1. What 'reader'/adapter (with a USB on the other end) should I buy so that I can read the drive in a Mac?
2. With the current Mac I am using, won't reading the files (from a windows) cause any formatting issues or troubles?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, [this is the adapter you need](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NAUIA6G)

For your second question, you will be able to read windows files from it as Mac can read FAT32 and NTFS filesystems (those are the types Windows uses).

Hope this answers your question!  If you need further details, let me know in the comments! :)

*EDIT*

I changed the Amazon link because the initial item had pretty bad reviews that I hadn't noticed but the new one looks good.  Sorry!

Comment: Note you won't be able to write to NTFS without 3rd party software, but reading is supported natively.